# Latex No Files found

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors, biber, external-files

I do not know what happened. I tried everything I found on line.
The problem is as follows: If I include `\addbibresource{example.bib}`, Latex stops recognizing any files. It doesn't matter what is in `example.bib`.
Everything is fine if it is excluded.

My Code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose,bibwarn=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setstretch {1,5}


\addbibresource{example.bib}

\date{}

\graphicspath{ {./Pictures/} }

\begin{document}
%TEST
\include{Hausarbeit_Titelseite}
\include{Einleitung_Aktuell}
%\section{Literatur}
%\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Output when I run Latex:

```
No file Hausarbeit_Main.bbl.
No file Hausarbeit_Titelseite.tex.
No file Einleitung_Aktuell.tex.
(Hausarbeit_Main.aux (Hausarbeit_Titelseite.aux) (Einleitung_Aktuell.aux)) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on Hausarbeit_Main.log.
```

The .bbl is not saved as .bbl.tex.
The .bbl does exist.
All documents are in the same file.
It appeared after I added soemthing to my .bib and didn't go away after I removed it. It is fixed if I remove the `\addbibresource{example.bib}`.

Output biber:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.17
INFO - Logfile is 'C:\Users\FamilieJanke\Desktop\Hausarbeit\Hausarbeit_Main.blg'
INFO - Reading 'C:\Users\FamilieJanke\Desktop\Hausarbeit\Hausarbeit_Main.bcf'
INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'example.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'C:\Users\FamilieJanke\Desktop\Hausarbeit\/example.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nty' and locale 'de-DE'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de-DE'
INFO - Writing 'C:\Users\FamilieJanke\Desktop\Hausarbeit\Hausarbeit_Main.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to C:\Users\FamilieJanke\Desktop\Hausarbeit\Hausarbeit_Main.bbl
```

Code of the example.bib:

```
@incollection{PlanertUte2009,
author = {Ute, Planert},
}

@incollection{HarrisonBrian2013,
author = {Brain, Harrison},
}

@online{BushJulia2007,
author = {Julia, Bush},
}
```

Hopefully someone can see what I did wrong :D

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Are you trying to compile with some absolut pathes?

Comment: Just to be on the safe side,  avoid underscores in file names and in cite or ref tags …

Comment: If you mean in the console: yes. I started using latex two months ago, had problems when I didn't. Worked until today :D

Comment: well you shouldn't call any program with say `pdflatex C:\somepath\whatever\Hausarbeit_Main`. Always switch into the folder of document and then use `pdflatex Hausarbeit_Main`.